# Corrupted excel file for large data

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, epplus

Hi i am using **EPPlus** to create xslx file with some data dump. It is working perfectly on local machine as well as on web server for small amount of data.

But i have a case where i have 40,000 rows in dataset. It is again working perfectly on local machine.

**but on server it is creating file and when i am trying to open that file it it showing error that file is corrupted. I tried editing file with notepad and noticed that it have HTML content in it**.

i am using this code:

```
public static void CreateExcel(string file_Name, DataSet ds)
{
    //  rowsPerSheet  = 50000; 
    string msg = "";
    string Type = "";
    using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage()) {
        //Create the worksheet
        ExcelWorksheet ws = default(ExcelWorksheet);
        int clCnt = 1;



        foreach (DataTable tbl in ds.Tables) {
            ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(tbl.TableName);

            //Load the datatable into the sheet, starting from cell A1. Print the column names on row 1
            ws.Cells("A1").LoadFromDataTable(tbl, true);

            if (tbl.Rows.Count != 0) {
                clCnt = 1;
                foreach (DataColumn col in tbl.Columns) {
                    ws.Column(clCnt).AutoFit();
                    // format all dates in german format (adjust accordingly)
                    if (col.DataType.Equals(typeof(System.DateTime))) {
                        dynamic colNumber = col.Ordinal + 1;
                        ExcelRange range = ws.Cells(2, colNumber, tbl.Rows.Count + 1, colNumber);
                        range.Style.Numberformat.Format = "MM/dd/yyyy";
                    }
                    if (col.DataType.Equals(typeof(System.Decimal)) || col.DataType.Equals(typeof(System.Double))) {
                        dynamic colNumber = col.Ordinal + 1;
                        ExcelRange range = ws.Cells(2, colNumber, tbl.Rows.Count + 1, colNumber);
                        range.Style.Numberformat.Format = "0.00";
                    }
                    clCnt += 1;
                }
            }
        }

        file_Name = file_Name.Replace(" ", "_") + ".xlsx";


        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=" + file_Name + "");

        HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }


}
```

Parent Function:

```
private void GenerateReport()
{
    string msg = "";
    string output = "where";
    int count = 0;
    string jsscript = "";
    string _FID = "";
    if ((ddlPortfolio.SelectedValue <= 0 & grvforecast.Rows.Count <= 0)) {
        jsscript = "<script>alert('Please select potfolio')</script>";
        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType, "jsclose", jsscript);
    } else if ((grvforecast.Rows.Count <= 0)) {
        jsscript = "<script>alert('Please add some entry in grid')</script>";
        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType, "jsclose", jsscript);
    } else {
        if (btnValue.Value == "Cash/GAAP Report") {
            _SqlStr = "[USP_CashGaapReport] '";
            foreach (GridViewRow row in grvforecast.Rows) {
                if ((count < grvforecast.Rows.Count - 1)) {
                    _SqlStr += "" + grvforecast.Rows(count).Cells(1).Text + ",";
                } else {
                    _SqlStr += "" + grvforecast.Rows(count).Cells(1).Text + "";
                }
                count = count + 1;
            }
            _SqlStr += "'";

        } else {
            if ((btnValue.Value == "Forecast Attribute Report")) {
                _SqlStr = "SELECT f.AttributeSetID as AttributeSetID , Attribute_Set.TabName as AttributeSetName FROM Forecast_Account as f INNER JOIN    Attribute_Set ON f.AttributeSetID = Attribute_Set.AttributeSetID where ";
            } else if ((btnValue.Value == "Forecast Data Report")) {
                _SqlStr = "SELECT p.LegalEntityName AS Portfolio, f.Name, c.AccountName, a.RepeatNumber, d.CashGAAP, d.TheDate, SUM(d.Amount) AS Amount, d.LastUpdated, d.UpdatedBy ";
                _SqlStr += "FROM dbo.Portfolio AS p INNER JOIN dbo.Forecast AS f ON p.PortfolioID = f.PortfolioID INNER JOIN dbo.Forecast_Account AS a ON f.ForecastID = a.ForecastID ";
                _SqlStr += "INNER JOIN dbo.Forecast_Data AS d ON a.ForecastAccountID = d.ForecastAccountID INNER JOIN dbo.CoA AS c ON c.AccountNumber = a.AccountNumber where ";
            } else {
                //    _SqlStr = "SELECT Portfolio, Name, AccountName, CashGAAP, OriginalDate, sum(Amount) as Amount, AccountNumber, AttributeSetName, TheDate, Year"
                //    _SqlStr &= " FROM (SELECT  Portfolio.LegalEntityName AS Portfolio, f.Name, CoA.AccountName, Forecast_Data.CashGAAP, CONVERT(date, Forecast_Data.TheDate) AS OriginalDate,"
                //    _SqlStr &= " SUM(Forecast_Data.Amount) AS Amount, CoA.AccountNumber, Attribute_Set.AttributeSetName, '' + CONVERT(varchar, YEAR(Forecast_Data.TheDate))"
                //    _SqlStr &= " + '-' + CONVERT(varchar, MONTH(Forecast_Data.TheDate)) + '-01' AS TheDate, YEAR(Forecast_Data.TheDate) AS Year, Forecast_Attribute.Value"
                //    _SqlStr &= " FROM   Portfolio INNER JOIN  Forecast AS f ON Portfolio.PortfolioID = f.PortfolioID INNER JOIN Forecast_Account ON f.ForecastID = Forecast_Account.ForecastID INNER JOIN Forecast_Data ON"
                //    _SqlStr &= " Forecast_Account.ForecastAccountID = Forecast_Data.ForecastAccountID INNER JOIN CoA ON CoA.AccountNumber = Forecast_Account.AccountNumber"
                //    _SqlStr &= " INNER JOIN Attribute_Set ON CoA.AttributeSetID = Attribute_Set.AttributeSetID INNER JOIN Forecast_Attribute ON Forecast_Account.ForecastAccountID = Forecast_Attribute.ForecastAccountID WHERE"
                _SqlStr = "SELECT Portfolio, Name, AccountName, CashGAAP, OriginalDate, sum(Amount) as Amount, d.AccountNumber as AccountNumber, AttributeSetName, TheDate, Year";
                _SqlStr += " FROM (SELECT  Portfolio.LegalEntityName AS Portfolio, f.Name, CoA.AccountName, Forecast_Data.CashGAAP, CONVERT(date, Forecast_Data.TheDate) AS OriginalDate,";
                _SqlStr += " SUM(Forecast_Data.Amount) AS Amount, CoA.AccountNumber, Attribute_Set.AttributeSetName, '' + CONVERT(varchar, YEAR(Forecast_Data.TheDate))";
                _SqlStr += " + '-' + CONVERT(varchar, MONTH(Forecast_Data.TheDate)) + '-01' AS TheDate, YEAR(Forecast_Data.TheDate) AS Year, Forecast_Attribute.Value";
                _SqlStr += " FROM   Portfolio INNER JOIN  Forecast AS f ON Portfolio.PortfolioID = f.PortfolioID INNER JOIN Forecast_Account ON f.ForecastID = Forecast_Account.ForecastID INNER JOIN Forecast_Data ON";
                _SqlStr += " Forecast_Account.ForecastAccountID = Forecast_Data.ForecastAccountID INNER JOIN CoA ON CoA.AccountNumber = Forecast_Account.AccountNumber";
                _SqlStr += " INNER JOIN Attribute_Set ON CoA.AttributeSetID = Attribute_Set.AttributeSetID INNER JOIN Forecast_Attribute ON Forecast_Account.ForecastAccountID = Forecast_Attribute.ForecastAccountID WHERE";
            }
            foreach (GridViewRow row in grvforecast.Rows) {
                if ((count < grvforecast.Rows.Count - 1)) {
                    _SqlStr += " f.ForecastID=" + grvforecast.Rows(count).Cells(1).Text + " or";
                    _FID += " a.ForecastID=" + grvforecast.Rows(count).Cells(1).Text + " or";
                } else {
                    _SqlStr += " f.ForecastID=" + grvforecast.Rows(count).Cells(1).Text + " ";
                    _FID += " a.ForecastID=" + grvforecast.Rows(count).Cells(1).Text + " ";
                }
                count = count + 1;
            }
            if ((btnValue.Value == "Forecast Data Report")) {
                _SqlStr += "GROUP BY p.LegalEntityName, f.Name, c.AccountName, a.RepeatNumber, d.CashGAAP, d.TheDate, d.LastUpdated, d.UpdatedBy";
            } else if ((btnValue.Value == "Cash/GAAP Report")) {
                _SqlStr += " GROUP BY Portfolio.LegalEntityName, f.Name, CoA.AccountName, Forecast_Data.CashGAAP, Forecast_Data.TheDate, CoA.AccountNumber, Attribute_Set.AttributeSetName, Forecast_Attribute.Value) AS d LEFT OUTER JOIN Vendor ON d.Value = Vendor.VendorName";
                _SqlStr += " GROUP BY d.OriginalDate, d.TheDate, d.AccountNumber, d.Portfolio, d.Name, d.AccountName, d.CashGAAP, d.AttributeSetName, d.Year, Vendor.VendorName";
                //    _SqlStr &= " GROUP BY Portfolio.LegalEntityName, f.Name, CoA.AccountName, Forecast_Data.CashGAAP, Forecast_Data.TheDate, CoA.AccountNumber, Attribute_Set.AttributeSetName, Forecast_Attribute.Value) AS d"
                //    _SqlStr &= " Group BY OriginalDate,TheDate,AccountNumber,Portfolio,Name,AccountName,CashGAAP,AttributeSetName,Year"
            }
        }
        try {
            if ((btnValue.Value != "Forecast Attribute Report")) {
                _ds = new DataSet();
                _dtTable = myDB.ExecuteDatatable(CommandType.Text, _SqlStr, null);
                _dtTable.TableName = btnValue.Value.Replace("_", " ");
                _ds.Tables.Add(_dtTable);
            } else {
                _ds = new DataSet();
                _SqlStr += "Group by f.AttributeSetID,Attribute_Set.TabName  ";
                _dtTable = myDB.ExecuteDatatable(CommandType.Text, _SqlStr, null);
                foreach (DataRow _dr in _dtTable.Rows) {
                    _SqlStr = "[USP_Forecast_Attributes] " + _dr["AttributeSetID"].ToString() + ",'" + _FID + "'";
                    _dtTable = myDB.ExecuteDatatable(CommandType.Text, _SqlStr, null);
                    _dtTable.TableName = _dr["AttributeSetName"].ToString();
                    _ds.Tables.Add(_dtTable);
                }
            }
            if ((_ds != null)) {
                if (DateAndTime.Now.IsDaylightSavingTime()) {
                    strTime = System.DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-5).ToString("_MM_dd_yyyy_hh_mm_tt");
                } else {
                    strTime = System.DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-4).ToString("_MM_dd_yyyy_hh_mm_tt");
                }
                if (btnValue.Value != "Forecast Attribute Report") {
                    epXL.CreateExcel(btnValue.Value, _ds);
                //epXL.ExportToExcel(_dtTable, btnValue.Value)
                } else {
                    epXL.CreateExcel(btnValue.Value, _ds);
                    // & strTime, _ds)
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            jsscript = "<script>alert('Report not generated')</script>";
            this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType, "jsclose", jsscript);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Now i got the exact error:

```
System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException: Unable to create mutex. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131464)
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.Open(String infoFile, String syncName)
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.Lock(Boolean& locked)
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, IsolatedStorageFile isf)
   at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.PackagingUtilities.SafeIsolatedStorageFileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, ReliableIsolatedStorageFileFolder folder)
   at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.PackagingUtilities.CreateUserScopedIsolatedStorageFileStreamWithRandomName(Int32 retryCount, String& fileName)
   at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.SparseMemoryStream.SwitchModeIfNecessary()
   at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.SparseMemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.CompressEmulationStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.CompressStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ProgressiveCrcCalculatingStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOModeEnforcingStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush(Boolean flushStream, Boolean flushEncoder)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Write(String value)
   at System.IO.TextWriter.Write(String format, Object arg0)
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet.UpdateRowCellData(StreamWriter sw)
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet.SaveXml()
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet.Save()
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorkbook.Save()
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage.GetAsByteArray(Boolean save)
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage.GetAsByteArray()
```

I am not able to resolve it. Please suggest. 
Thanks

Comment: When you say 'it has html content in it': what does it say?

Comment: it is the content of whole aspx page. The page in which i have this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Now I got your problem.
I think this is due to write permission issue on the server.
 Generally ASP.net user doesnt have write permission outside the Application folder. 
Here are two link might help you.

1. [Unable to create mutex. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131464)](https://epplus.codeplex.com/workitem/14877)
2. [IsolatedStorageException: Unable to create the store directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035576/isolatedstorageexception-unable-to-create-the-store-directory)

Hope this help you.

Comment: it is a godaddy server. how can i check RAM there?

Comment: Now I got your problem.
I think this is due to write permission issue on the server.
 Generally ASP.net user doesnt have write permission outside the Application folder. Here are two link might help you.
1.  [link](https://epplus.codeplex.com/workitem/14877)
2.  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035576/isolatedstorageexception-unable-to-create-the-store-directory)

Comment: It's not related to RAM.  The internal SparseMemoryStream class will try to load anything into Isolated Storage if it's over 1MB.  The MS Packaging API uses this class under the hood to open streams inside of packages. -- you might be better off using another library like CSharpZipLib/SAX parsing when the files are too large.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a design issue in your page. At least, the quick fix is to add this before your write the document to the `Response`.

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
```

When you have the response in the output, it means it tries to render a page and in it, you try to do something else, in this case writing the file. (See [How can I return a pdf from a web request in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057836/how-can-i-return-a-pdf-from-a-web-request-in-asp-net) as an example).

We have to see more of your code to check this completely, but I guess you don't use a `HttpHandler` for this which I would recommend.

```
public class DownloadFileHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        Response.BinaryWrite(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: but it is working in local machine. and on server it is working for other smaller files.

Comment: Can you show more context please? How is the method called?

Comment: its simple. i am getting data from database into a dataset and simply passing that data to this function.

Comment: @DeepSharma: what is the action before? Is it an ASPX page? If so, you really should call the `Clear` method.

Comment: @DeepSharma: Can you add more of the surrounding code. I got this working over here...

Comment: the file downloaded by this code is 80kb and on my local machine(with the same code) it is of 1.7 MB.

Comment: Did you try putting this in a HttpHandler? That is better since you have full control over the output and makes analyzing easier. Just create a new HttpHandler and put your code in the ProcessRequest. (See example).

Comment: can you please explain it according to my code. it will be really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. You combine writing script code and binary file output in the same page. That is just wrong. With a HttpHandler you can create custom url handlers. Resulting url for example: http://localhost/FileDownloadHandler.ashx?id=123

Comment: one more thing. if i use direct function without using epplus dll. then it works fine giving an xls file of 7.1 MB.

Comment: @DeepSharma: I still have no clue, but I think you should restructure this to get a better view on the problem.

Comment: i have posted the exact error that i am getting please see my edit.

Comment: have you got any solution?

Comment: @DeepSharma: can you create a sample that does not need database interaction? I can't test it now.