# {"The type initializer for 'SAP.Logon.Core.LogonCore' threw an exception."} Unable to create the store directory. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131468)

Tags: c#, bots, sap-smp

I am using SAP SDK In Microsoft bot application. Its working fine for me in local emulator, but after publishing this bot application on azure portal I got this exception.

> {"The type initializer for 'SAP.Logon.Core.LogonCore' threw an exception."}
>   Unable to create the store directory. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131468)

I was getting exception when I am trying to initialize the `logonCore` Object.

```
SharedContext.Context.LogonCoreObj = await 
  LogonCore.InitWithApplicationIdAsync(SharedContext.Context.ApplicationID);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IsolatedStorageException: Unable to create the store directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035576/isolatedstorageexception-unable-to-create-the-store-directory)

Comment: I am using SAP sdk. I dont have any other option to change this IsolatedStorageCode . Can u give me brief description for same.

Comment: How do you run your app pool ?

Comment: Hi Bob, I did't get you . what is pool?

Comment: It's a web application(Using Bot framework)

Comment: Hi , i did't get any option to set LOADUSERPROFILE tot true.

Comment: Hey , I  am following this tutorial to publish my app . here and azure portal  also i did't find any pool where i update my advance setting.                                     http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/publishing-your-bot-application-to-azure/